# Is there any javascript performace profiler,such as xhprof for php

Tags: javascript, performance, web-applications

JavaScript is becoming the biggest killer of web application, especially for mobile Webapp.

But I haven't found a simple and useful tools like xphrof to help me analysis the problem of my JavaScript code.

Firebug, Google Speed Tracer, and dynatrace are great tools, but their usability is not very well, they do not support mobile app and also can not be used for as a service.

Are there any tools can be used as easy as xhprof?

With this tools, what I need to do is: mark the code that need to be analysed, open browser, do actions, and then go to visit a page which can tell me the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of them exist. Although i think firebug might be more suitable for what you are asking.

### Chrome Dev Tools:

Go through the links below for more,

```
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/cpu-profiling
```

### Firebug:

Firebug provides a highly detailed profiling report. It will tell you how long each method invocation takes

```
console.profile([title])
console.profileEnd ()
```

also take a look at `console.trace()`

Take a look at the console API here, http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API

Comment: Firebug can help me in some case. But for mobile webapp, we can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

i love using chrome developer tools for profiling my app and get some memory leaks indication, you can take live snapshot from your app, you can watch re-painting of elements, you can take a deep look on your objects and optimize it by using `delete` if you don't need keep using them, big like on it:)